# How to vaildate CSV file data column by column?

Tags: python, csv, validation

I am new to python and am trying to read a csv file and validate the data to make sure that all data is within specific ranges. Each column has different specifications.

Example: 
All data in column 0 must be between 1 and 500
All data in column 1 must be between 2.5 and 50.5

I can read the csv without issues but when I try to validate the data for one column it seems like maybe only the first entry is being validated and the program is just reprinting the pass or fail of the first entry for each row.

Example csv file:

```
1,2
100,2.5
1000,3.5
```

```py
#looking for just greater than or equal to 1

import csv

with open("csvdata.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if 1 <= row[0]:
            print "pass"
        else:
            print "fail"

#looking for greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 500

import csv

with open("csvdata.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if 1 <= row[0] <= 500:
            print "pass"
        else:
            print "fail"
```

I expect the first snippet to produce:

```
pass
pass
pass
```

which it does, but when I changed it from  `if 1 < row[0]:` to `if 10000 < row[0]:` still gives all pass messages.

I expect the second snippet to produce:

```
pass
pass
fail
```

but it produces:

```
fail
fail
fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks nearly correct, but your validation message doesn't tell you very much that is useful, which is why you can't tell accurately if it is working.

The main thing you need to fix is that values in a .csv are strings so the test `if 1 <= row[0] <= 500` will not work as you expect, and in Python 3 would give you a helpful error message instead of quietly doing the unexpected. Convert the number to an `int` before doing the comparison.

```
with open("csvdata.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ",")
    for row in csvreader:
        if 1 <= int(row[0]) <= 500:
            print "row {0} pass value is in range".format(csvreader.line_num)
        else:
            print "row {0} fail value is {1} out of range".format(csvreader.line_num, row[0])
```

As a side note, if you are new to Python, you really should not be investing effort in learning Python 2. Please consider installing Python 3 and concentrating your effort on that.

Comment: Your validation message is much better and helps, the value is getting passed in the message, but the if statement doesn't seem to work correctly. When I run it I get "row 1 fail value is 1 out of range, row 2 fail value is 100 out of range, row 3 fail value is 1000 out of range". I'm not sure why it is passing the correct value in the message, but not validating correctly.

Comment: +100 for the advice to switch to Python 3. There's really no reason to invest in working with a version that is not only obsolete, but inferior in this and other respects.

Comment: See edited answer. Your comment pointed me at a Python 2 specific problem I hadn't seen.

Comment: It worked thanks for help and the advice. I'll start looking into Python 3